# Delaying select2 opening to fill it with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have  a dropdown which I'm filling data by calling a function `list()`, which makes json calls and filters necessary data according to different parameters (It's very complex, and I'm not using the built in ajax feature).

Here's my code:

```
$("select.mission:visible").on("select2-opening", function() {  list(); });
```

It works flawlessly, except for one little problem - updating the list is done while opening so the updated list doesn't show when you first open the dropdown. On the second open it shows the correct options.

I considered using `select2-focus`, but it's called twice, in the beginning and in the end. The second call repopulates the list and while the selected option is still highlighted, the value passes down as `undefined`.

The solution I look for is delaying the opening of the list to let it populate.
Any ideas in this direction or another?

Comment: Can you not populate it the moment you get the data so when the user clicks it just opens?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I'm not sure I understand correctly, but right now the code I wrote works, it just doesn't show up the right results on the first open

Comment: At some point you're getting the data which you want to populate the select.  You haven't given info as to *when* that happens but it *has* to happen before the select opens right?  Try and populate it in advance so on first click everything is there already.  i.e. don't wait until the user has clicked to trigger the populating of the list

Comment: @RobSchmuecker  The function ˋlist()ˋpopulates the data as it's called. I already succeeded to create a "refresh" button, but  it ruins the workflow, and I don't have any other triggers. I tried assigning a simple "click" event, but it doesn't pass down at all.

Comment: What do you mean "as it's called"?  Can you show more code?

Comment: Here's the basic function of `list()`:
`function list(location) {

 $.getJSON("path-to-json",
 function(data) {
  $('select.missions').empty();
  $('select.missions').append('<option class="empty"></option>'); // append one empty selection
  $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, entry) {
   //do stuff
  });
 });
}`

Comment: @wallace, have you found the solution yet ?

Comment: @wallace, what version of select2 are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit late for this question. I have the similar problem as you and I have solve it as below:

```
$("select.mission:visible").on("select2-open", function() {  
                            $.getJSON("path-to-json",   function(data) {
                                        var results_data = [];
                                        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, entry) {
                                            results_data.push({'id':entry.id, 'text':entry.text}) 
                                        });
                                        // if your element select.mission:visible is select convert it to input:hidden
                                        var id = $(this).attr('id') // get old id
                                        var name = $(this).attr('name') // get old name
                                        var oldVal = $(this).val() // get old value
                                        $('select.missions').empty(); // empty select options
                                        $(this).select2('distroy') // destroy current select2 obj
                                        $(this).replaceWith(`<input type='hidden' class='mission' id='${id}' name='${name}'>`) // convert select element to input element
                                        $(this).val(oldVal) // set new input element to previous value
                                        $(this).select2({data:results_data}) // set new option items to new input element select2
                                        $(this).select2('open') // force select2 element to open dropdown

                            }); 
                        });
```

Because I don't know which version of select2 you're using, but from your code, I assumed you are using select2 version 3.x. For more detail check it at https://select2.github.io/select2/